# How to create multiple binary C++ netbeans project?

Tags: c++, netbeans

In my C++ linux project I wanna create daemon executable that forks and executes actual executable. I couldn't find a facility in netbeans IDE to create multiple main files that compile into corresponding executables. Need help in doing it in Netbeans IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans uses generated makefiles, those don't allow multiple `main()`-functions. As a solution you can write your own makefile.

However, you can use [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) with NetBeans instead (personal recommendation). CMake allows you to compile several executable / libraries in one run.

Some advantages (respective to your problem):

- Managing and compilation of multiple projects - each separated or all together
- Not limited to Netbeans - CMake can generate project- or makefiles for various IDE's, even commanline-building is possible
- Clean separation of actual code and build stuff

NetBeans supports CMake, so it will build as usual; you just have to write a `CMakeLists.txt` (~ a makefile) by your own - but thanks to good documentation this wont be a huge problem.

Comment: yeah I've seen cmake command specified in C/C++ preferences. Now how to build my project using cmake instead of make? Should I just have to change Makefile to cmake interpretable format?

Comment: No, better create a new *project with existing sources*. There you select the base directory of your project (= where the main `CMakeLists.txt` is) and continue as usual. If all is ok, NB will CMake and build your project.

Comment: Btw. a good tip: When creating such a project, select *configuration mode = custom*, and on the next page select *Run configure script in subfolder* (`build` is the default value there) -- continue with next until finished. This little setting will place all local cmake stuff (= cmake cache) in a folder `build` and therefore keeps your project dir clean of such files. But as i said before, it's just a tip - using *automatic* will work fine too.

Comment: I never used cmake before. I should dig into it. So can't I create new project with cmake as default?

Comment: CMake-based project are handled a bit different. Normal projects create all necessary files (makefiles etc.) for you. If you use CMake, you write a cmake file (`CMakeLists.txt`) and tell netbeans to make a project with that. This sounds more complex than it actually is, you'll see :-) Cmake has a great documentation and lots of examples around (btw. if you have your basic skeleton you can use this for almost all projects with minor changes).

Comment: As a start, here's a [here's](http://mathnathan.com/2010/07/getting-started-with-cmake/) a tutorial (no special one, just the first out of the blue ... but this enough for a start) and [here's](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html) the Cmake documentation. If your cmake list is ready (in the tutorial it's the part after *"CMake Syntax"* you can already feed it into netbeans.